# Return in only one table info from two tables into rows when info is in columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

In PostgreSQL I have 2 tables with fields:

- Working_date: `id` (autonumeric), `employee_code` (varchar (6)), `working_date` (date), `working_hour` (time),
- Attendance: `id` (autonumeric), `employee_code` (varchar (6)), `attendance_date` (date), `attendance_hour` (time),

Data example:

Working_date

```
ID  | employee_code | working_date | working_hour
1   | 12345         | 2015-07-09   | 08:00
2   | 12345         | 2015-07-09   | 13:00
3   | 12345         | 2015-07-09   | 14:00
4   | 12345         | 2015-07-09   | 17:00
5   | 12345         | 2015-07-10   | 08:00
6   | 12345         | 2015-07-10   | 13:00
7   | 12345         | 2015-07-10   | 14:00
8   | 12345         | 2015-07-10   | 17:00
9   | 12345         | 2015-07-11   | 08:00
10  | 12345         | 2015-07-11   | 13:00
11  | 12345         | 2015-07-11   | 14:00
12  | 12345         | 2015-07-11   | 17:00
13  | 12345         | 2015-07-12   | 08:00
14  | 12345         | 2015-07-12   | 13:00
15  | 12345         | 2015-07-12   | 14:00
16  | 12345         | 2015-07-12   | 17:00
17  | 12345         | 2015-07-13   | 08:00
18  | 12345         | 2015-07-13   | 13:00
19  | 12345         | 2015-07-13   | 14:00
20  | 12345         | 2015-07-13   | 17:00
```

Attendance

```
ID  | employee_code | attendance_date | attendance_hour
1   | 12345         | 2015-07-09      | 07:56:53
2   | 12345         | 2015-07-09      | 10:33:31
3   | 12345         | 2015-07-09      | 13:00:42
4   | 12345         | 2015-07-09      | 13:00:47
5   | 12345         | 2015-07-09      | 13:30:21
6   | 12345         | 2015-07-09      | 17:00:01
7   | 12345         | 2015-07-10      | 07:48:35
8   | 12345         | 2015-07-10      | 12:15:20
9   | 12345         | 2015-07-10      | 13:58:42
10  | 12345         | 2015-07-10      | 17:02:00
11  | 12345         | 2015-07-11      | 08:06:46
12  | 12345         | 2015-07-11      | 12:00:01
13  | 12345         | 2015-07-11      | 13:52:01
14  | 12345         | 2015-07-11      | 17:05:08
15  | 12345         | 2015-07-12      | 07:55:02
16  | 12345         | 2015-07-12      | 12:03:22
17  | 12345         | 2015-07-12      | 13:37:40
18  | 12345         | 2015-07-12      | 17:05:01
19  | 12345         | 2015-07-13      | 07:54:25
20  | 12345         | 2015-07-13      | 10:44:15
21  | 12345         | 2015-07-13      | 13:59:21
22  | 12345         | 2015-07-13      | 17:01:17
```

In table "Attendance" there are some repetitive rows because employee entered attendance more than once. For example on 2015-07-09 there are 2 attendance times (13:00:42, 13:00:47) when it is time to go out for lunch. In this case, I should get only one of the two records.

The other case on 2015-07-09 there is 10:33:31. It is recorded when the employee asks permission to leave work and then returns in this case at 13:00:42 / 13:00:47.

Is there a way for getting `working_date`, `working_hour` with its respective `attendance_hour` in one table with only pure SQL queries (maybe some type of subqueries)?

Example:

```
ID  | employee_code | working_date | working_hour1 | attendance_time_1 | working_hour2 | attendance_time_2    | working_hour3 | attendance_time_3 | working_hour4 | attendance_time_4
1   | 12345         | 2015-07-09   | 08:00         | 07:56:53          | 13:00:00      | 13:00:42 or 13:00:47 | 14:00         | 13:30:21          | 17:00         | 17:00:01
2   | 12345         | 2015-07-10   | 08:00         | 07:48:35          | 13:00:00      | 12:15:20             | 14:00         | 13:58:42          | 17:00         | 17:02:00
3   | 12345         | 2015-07-11   | 08:00         | 08:06:46          | 13:00:00      | 12:00:01             | 14:00         | 13:52:01          | 17:00         | 17:05:08
4   | 12345         | 2015-07-12   | 08:00         | 07:55:02          | 13:00:00      | 12:03:22             | 14:00         | 13:37:40          | 17:00         | 17:05:01
5   | 12345         | 2015-07-13   | 08:00         | 07:54:25          | 13:00:00      | 10:44:15             | 14:00         | 13:59:21          | 17:00         | 17:01:17
```

In case it is not possible to get it with pure SQL querie, how can it achieved with maybe PL/PGSQL?

Currently I make it with PHP like this:

- I query `employee_code` and `working_date` fields from `working_date` table. This query is run between 2 dates: `from_date`, `to_date`.
- Inside a "for statement" I consult with every row of working_date all the working_hour rows: `working_hour1`, `working_hour2`, `working_hour3`, `working_hour4`. For every row is run an SQL query. For this query I send it `employee_code` and `working_date` parameters.
- Inside a nested "for statement", with every `working_hour`, I run a query to "attendance_date" table with parameters: `employee_code`, `working_date` and `working_hour`. It returns the `attendance_hour` for every `working_hour`.

This way (calling SELECTS from PHP with nested "for statement") is too slow for getting and showing the info. I see the process when executing it and process takes 100% of CPU.

Answer (score 0):

You can join those tables on their dates and aggregate the attendance times into an array by grouping by date and employee_code somewhat like this:

```
SELECT
w.employee_code, 
w.working_date,
array_agg(distinct(w.working_hour)) working_hours,
array_agg(distinct(a.attendance_hour)) attendance_hours
FROM Working_date w
LEFT JOIN attendance a
ON (w.working_date = a.attendance_date)
GROUP BY w.working_date, w.employee_code
ORDER BY w.working_date
```

You could use the *unnest()* function of postgres to unnest those arrays, but it will put them into new *rows* not columns. Putting them into separate columns is difficult because those arrays probably won't be the same length and all rows have to have the same columns.

Heres a fiddle
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/2a75c/7/0